# Flutter dart compiled fail due to EdgeInsets.all

Tags: dart, flutter

When I ran "flutter run" and try to see the results, I got the errors as shown below.

It seems to be related to EdgeInsets. Below are my source codes that I am still working on.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<String> _products = ['Food Tester'];
  build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('EasyList'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin:  EdgeInsets.all(8.0,2),
            child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('Add product'),
          ),
          ),
        Column(children: _products.map((element) =>Card(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[Image.asset("assets/food.jpg"), Text(element)],
            ),
          )).toList()),

        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Below are the errors:

```
    $ flutter run --debug
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       1.4s
Resolving dependencies...                                    1.3s
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...                               
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:68:24: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     this.margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
compiler message:                        ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:113:33: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:         margin: margin ?? const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
compiler message:                                 ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/chip_theme.dart:233:46: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     const EdgeInsetsGeometry padding = const EdgeInsets.all(4.0);
compiler message:                                              ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart:123:25: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:         padding = const EdgeInsets.all(8.0);
compiler message:                         ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expand_icon.dart:28:25: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     this.padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0)
compiler message:                         ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_panel.dart:159:30: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
compiler message:                              ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/icon_button.dart:75:25: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     this.padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
compiler message:                         ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_border.dart:319:16: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     return new EdgeInsets.all(borderSide.width);
compiler message:                ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/outline_button.dart:440:16: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     return new EdgeInsets.all(side.width);
compiler message:                ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/popup_menu.dart:818:25: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     this.padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
compiler message:                         ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/progress_indicator.dart:542:21: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:       margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0), // accommodate the shadow
compiler message:                     ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/progress_indicator.dart:548:26: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
compiler message:                          ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/stepper.dart:601:28: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
compiler message:                            ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tabs.dart:1205:21: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:       margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
compiler message:                     ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart:1528:22: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
compiler message:                      ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/beveled_rectangle_border.dart:46:16: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     return new EdgeInsets.all(side.width);
compiler message:                ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/circle_border.dart:35:16: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     return new EdgeInsets.all(side.width);
compiler message:                ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/rounded_rectangle_border.dart:45:16: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     return new EdgeInsets.all(side.width);
compiler message:                ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/rounded_rectangle_border.dart:160:16: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     return new EdgeInsets.all(side.width);
compiler message:                ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/stadium_border.dart:36:16: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     return new EdgeInsets.all(side.width);
compiler message:                ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/stadium_border.dart:143:16: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     return new EdgeInsets.all(side.width);
compiler message:                ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/stadium_border.dart:296:16: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:     return new EdgeInsets.all(side.width);
compiler message:                ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/button.dart:33:42: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message: const EdgeInsets _kButtonPadding = const EdgeInsets.all(16.0);
compiler message:                                          ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/dialog.dart:276:22: Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.
compiler message:         padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0 * textScaleFactor),
compiler message:                      ^
compiler message: file:///Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/edge_insets.dart:336:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
compiler message:   const EdgeInsets.all(double value, int i)
compiler message:         ^^^
Compiler failed on /Users/Ashley/development/flutter_course_app/lib/main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/Ashley/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 435

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/Ashley/development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Gradle build failed: 1
```

Comment: Please use the code formatting for your error log, it improves readability.

Answer (score 1):

`EdgeInsets.all` accepts only one parameter (see [`EdgeInsets.all` api docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets/EdgeInsets.all.html)). As you wrote `EdgeInsets.all(8.0,2)` there's a compilation error.

Comment: But why these errors though? He gets error on libraries stating `Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given.`

Comment: I suspect that something went wrong during dev process. After using `EdgeInsets.all(8.0,2)` the IDE might have provided a quick fix to add missing parameter to the constructor without seeing that the refactoring was done in external code.

Comment: @JackmanLee If you want to add `(8.0,2)` you can use `EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 2.0)` or `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0)`

Comment: I tried EdgeInsets.all(8.0), EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 2.0) or EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0).  But I still got same errors.

Comment: It looks like you have an issue with your flutter setup. You should consider to re-install it.

Comment: The wired thing is that when I created a new app and I did not use EdgeInsets at all. But when I tried to  build and run the new app, I still got the previous errors complaining about the EdgeInsets.

Comment: Like I said before _It looks like you have an issue with your flutter setup_ you should re-install Flutter.

Answer (score -2):

Use margin:  **EdgeInsets.all(8.0),**